# Search for data block in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have been working with ElasticSearch which is new to me. Currently I am logging some status messages on an external PC which is send to my database (this is out of my reach). I collect this data by giving a start and end time to make my query. But the challenge for me is to get the data BEFORE my query, so if I make a search for 17-08-2017 to 18-08-2017 I want to see the logging that happend the day before on the last hour, cause if I just change the starting date to a day before my query date it gives me to many results, so ideal I would like a data block of 200 log rules which dynamically changes on scrolling through the data. Hope my question is understandable!

Not sure if my current query is relevant, so please ask me if you want it :)

Greetings,

Bram

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use the scan method available under helpers module. This gives you a cursor(iterator) to loop over the response.

```
helpers.scan(es,
     query={
        "query": {
          "range": {
            "date_field": {
              "gte": "17-08-2017",
              "lte": "18-08-2017"
             }
           }
         }
     },
     index="my-index",
     doc_type="my-type"
)
```

Now you can easily batch the response in size of 200 by breaking the iteration.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I will try this out in the comming days and come back to you.

Comment: did you get a chance to try it out @wesselink